# Understanding Rouché's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The theorem claims that two functions have the same numbers of zeros ''inside'' a curve (wikipedia). Does it means interior or the closure?
If it means interior, can there exist a case we have on the boundary different numbers of zeros?
If it means closure, can it be the total numbers of zeros are the same but different on boundary and interior?

Comment: In the interior of the region.

Answer (score 1):

The interior of a closed piece-wise smooth curve $\gamma : [0,1]\to\Bbb C$ in reasonable generality is the set of points $z\in \mathbb C$ such that $\gamma$ winds around $z$ a nonzero number of times. Here, the winding number of $\gamma$ around $z$ is defined to be the integral 
$$W(\gamma,z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{dw}{w-z}$$
which one can prove always evaluates to an integer. For nice enough curves, say those that are the smooth boundary of a compact set, it is true this generalized interior coincides with the usual interior of the compact set. In general, expect pathologies.

Comment: Is there any proof to this equivalence?

Comment: @CO2 Probably, but I don't know of a reference off the top of my head.